# GPG and PGP keyring compatibile

Tags: gnupg, pgp-desktop, gpg4win

I have PGP Desktop 8.1 installed (PGP Corp)
I wonder if I can use GPG with same keyring as PGP does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prior to GPG 2.7, use [this guide](http://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/pgp2x.html), it allows PGP by adding the extension modules IDEA & RSA to GPG.

In more recent GPG versions, **RSA** is supported so you can use the same keyring as PGP.

Comment: This guide is about PGP 2.6 from 1999. GPG has supported RSA keys for quite a while already.

Comment: @grawity: Thanks for clarifying, I'll update...